# Objective-C: getNotificationSettingsWithCompletionHandler assign to variable from completion handler. How?

Tags: objective-c

I've got stacked on very simple issue. Hasn't been using Objective-C a lot at last time. Could someone help me with:

```
+(UNAuthorizationStatus) mCheckPermissions {

__block UNAuthorizationStatus oOutput = 0;

UNUserNotificationCenter* oCenter = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
[oCenter getNotificationSettingsWithCompletionHandler:^(UNNotificationSettings * _Nonnull settings) {
    oOutput = settings.authorizationStatus;
}];

return oOutput;
}
```

I need assign the value to oOutput from completion handler. For now it's not assinning value correctly. What am I missing? And please do not reply me something Swift related. The question is about Objective-C.

Comment: Your completion handler runs asynchronously, which means it is not going to execute until after `return oOutput;`.    You need to either use the value in the handler or signal some other code that the value is ready in the handler...or use synchronization, which is generally a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

What you're missing is that `getNotificationSettingsWithCompletionHandler` is *asynchronous.*

That means that the "answer" within the block (your `settings.authorizationStatus`) comes back to you *after* the entire `mCheckPermissions` method has finished executing, including the `return`. The order of execution is like this:

```
+(UNAuthorizationStatus) mCheckPermissions {

    __block UNAuthorizationStatus oOutput = 0;

    /* 1 */ UNUserNotificationCenter* oCenter = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
    /* 2 */ [oCenter getNotificationSettingsWithCompletionHandler:^(UNNotificationSettings * _Nonnull settings) {
        /* 4 */ oOutput = settings.authorizationStatus;
    }];
    /* 3 */ return oOutput;
}
```

Therefore it is *impossible* to return, from the outer method `mCheckPermissions`, a value that arrives into the block. (Unless you have a time machine in your pocket, so you can dip into the future and find out what the result *will* be.)

Comment: Here's an online article about that: http://www.programmingios.net/returning-a-value-from-asynchronous-code/ And don't give me guff about the programming language in which the example code is written in that article. The _facts_ would be the same in Objective-C, Ruby, Python, or Snortiblog. Asynchronous is asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

Solution found. Issue closed.

```
+(UNAuthorizationStatus) mCheckPermissions {

__block UNAuthorizationStatus oOutput = UNAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined;
dispatch_semaphore_t oSemaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

UNUserNotificationCenter* oCenter = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
[oCenter getNotificationSettingsWithCompletionHandler:^(UNNotificationSettings * _Nonnull settings) {
    oOutput = settings.authorizationStatus;
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(oSemaphore);
}];

if (![NSThread isMainThread]) {
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(oSemaphore,DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
} else {
    while (dispatch_semaphore_wait(oSemaphore,DISPATCH_TIME_NOW)) {
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0]];
    }
}

return oOutput;
}
```

Comment: Philip Mills is right in its comment of your question: "or use synchronization, which is generally a bad idea.". I wouldn't recommend your code. Instead, I'd manage asynchrone code, which is an issue you'll encounter later in many codes (web requests, etc.)